# Why can't I escape quote in gawk?

Tags: linux, shell, gawk

I'm trying to do the following, but either I'm way too tired and can't think, or something weird is hapening with the escapes:

```
scanimage -L | gawk '/N650U/ {print gensub("[\'`]", "", "g", $2)}'
pipe bquote>
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The idiom to do this is to create a variable which contains the single quote and then use that:

```
scanimage -L | gawk '/N650U/ {print gensub(q"`", "", "g", $2)}' q="'"
```

However, since you are using it in a character class, that is not going to work so you'll need to do this:

```
scanimage -L | gawk '/N650U/ {print gensub("[`'\'']", "", "g", $2)}'
                    <--      1st pair       -->  <--   2nd pair  -->
```

Another alternative if using `bash` is to use `$''` which *does* support escaping single-quotes

```
scanimage -L | gawk $'/N650U/ {print gensub("[`\']", "", "g", $2)}'
```

All you are doing in the 2nd case is creating a single-quote pair right before your literal single-quote, escaping the single quote so the shell doesn't interpret it and then make another single-quote pair after it.

#### Example with single-quote in a regex

```
$ echo $'foo`\'' | awk '{gsub(/[o`'\'']/,"#")}1'
f####
```

#### Example with single-quote outside a regex

```
$ echo "foo" | awk '{print q$0q}' q="'"
'foo'
```

#### Example with single-quote inside `$''`

```
echo $'foo`\'' | awk $'{gsub(/[o`\']/,"#")}1'
f####
```

Comment: That first line won't work, as you have the q *inside* the double quotes: you want `gensub(q"\", ""...`

Comment: NO. The idiom to do this is to use `\047` instead. When you use a variable you are forcing awk to use a string literal instead of a regexp literal and so forcing yourself to double-escape everything (see the man page or google it). Simply use `foo\047bar` to represent `foo'bar` and avoid all the headaches. Note that this only applies to single-quote-delimited scripts, if your script is stored in a file and invoked as `awk -f script` then you can just use literal single quotes.

Comment: @EdMorton I don't think we're going to get very far arguing what is and what isn't an idiom as it's extremely subjective.  I do thank you for your comment, although I would prefer using `$''` over `\047` if I wasn't concerned with extreme portability.

Comment: What effect, if any, does `$''` have other than allowing you to embed single quotes in the script? It seems unlikely to me that that's ALL it does but it'd be great to know for sure.

Answer (score 2):

There's **no** special character in [single quotes](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Single-Quotes) including backslash(`\`).

> Enclosing characters in single quotes (`'`) preserves the literal value of each character within the quotes. A single quote may not occur between single quotes, even when preceded by a backslash.

You can change the command to:

```
$ scanimage -L | awk '/N650U/ {print gensub("['"'"'`]", "", "g", $2)}'
```

Comment: Thanks for this, it is exactly what I was searching for. Could you briefly explain what the ` character is for in the regex ['"'"'`] please

Comment: @JackalopeZero add extra spaces to the command: `'...'  "..." '...'` . It's very simple: concat three strings together.

Comment: you need to remove spaces to concat. It's hard to read. It's easy to understand.

Answer (score 1):

Shell '...' doesn't support backslash escapes. You'll have to use "..." instead, I'm afraid.

```
gawk "/N650U/ {print gensub(\"['`]\", \"\", \"g\", \$2)}\"
```

(Note that shell "..." *does* expand $ variables, so you need to escape that as well!)

Comment: easier to just escape the one single quote

Comment: To be honest, the only way to stay sane in a nasty maze of quotation characters and backslashes in this sort of thing is to put the gawk script in its own file.

Answer (score 0):

```
gawk '/N650U/ {print gensub("[\'`]", "", "g", $2)}'
     ^                         ^
     beginning of sq string       end of single quoted string
```

A bit ugly, but this works:

```
gawk '/N650U/ {print gensub("['"'"'`]", "", "g", $2)}'
```

Comment: rather than double quote it, just escape it. Ugly but not *as* ugly

Comment: right, its one less character but I also think its easier to see that a single-quote is being used with `"['\'']"` than `"['"'"']"`. Maybe just me, dunno

Answer (score 0):

The correct way to do this is simply:

```
scanimage -L | gawk '/N650U/ {print gensub(/[\047`]/, "", "g", $2)}'
```

It doesn't affect using `\047` for a single quote but as an aside given all of the other posted solutions are using string delimiters, note the use of regexp delimiters instead of string delimiters around the regexp that is gsub()s first argument. It matters, see for example:

```
$ printf 'a\\tb\n' | awk '{sub(/\\t/,"X")}1'
aXb
$ printf 'a\\tb\n' | awk '{sub("\\t","X")}1'
a\tb
$ printf 'a\\tb\n' | awk '{sub("\\\\t","X")}1'
aXb
```

The only time to use string delimiters in a regexp context is when you need to concatenate a literal with a variable, e.g.:

```
awk '{sub("<"var">","")}1'
```

Look up string and regexp delimiters in the man page for details.